# How to not display the tooltip on a span element when exporting to an Excel file in DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

Can anyone please let me know -how to not display span tag which contain `class='tooltips'`, and contain some long paragraph as `data-original-title=""`. I want this data which displays here, but again, not `</span>`.

So in the following code:

```
<span class="tooltips" id="493002" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.">**This is bold**</span>
```

I have tried following two codes but not working well as I can't remove span tag and as a result it will appear on excel file when export....

```
$('#rname').DataTable({
    ordering: true,
    paging: true,
    searching: true,
    "pageLength": 30,

    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
    buttons: [
    'copy', 
        'csv', 
        'excel',
        'pdf', 
        'print'
    ]
});

/* not working
$('#rnames').DataTable({
    ordering: true,
    paging: true,
    searching: true,
    "pageLength": 30,

    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
    buttons: [
      {
           extend: 'excel',
           exportOptions: {

               format: {
                    body: function ( data, row, column, node ) {
                        // Strip $ from salary column to make it numeric
                        return column === 2 ?
                            data.replace(/".*?"/g, ''):
                            data;
                    } 

                },
                 stripHtml: false  
           }               
       },
            'copy', 
        'csv', 
        'pdf', 
        'print' 
    ]
});
```

I want to remove `<span>`, but keep whatever's between the `<span>` tags. Like in the above example, the content would be "This is bold". I want this text to show on the Excel file when I export.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the **[.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)** property to extract the contents inside of the tag. You can target `<span>` tags specifically with [**document.getElementsByTagName('span')**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName).

In the following example there's only one `<span>` tag, so it is accessible from index `[0]`:

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML);
```

```html
<span class="tooltips" id="493002" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.">**This is bold**</span>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: No I am not asking this at all, All I want is to not display span tag when I export tables data into dataTables export option.

Comment: From your question, it sounded as though you were attempting to target the content in JavaScript. Could you please update your question to include your `.DataTable()` jQuery code and HTML table?